# In VHDL, is it synthesizable to use variables other than i,j in FOR loops?

Tags: for-loop, vhdl, synthesis

I am a freshman to VHDL, and am learning it by myself.

As a practice, I am doing a data process (calculate spatial average data) to a 320*240 graphic data.
I am considering the way like this :
1. Create a 10*10 cluster of homogeneous simple elements, where each element calculates the average value of a single pixel.
2. Each time connect one portion of the graphic data to the 10*10 cluster, make calculation then change connection. And after 32*24 times of operation, the work is finished.

But I got synthesizing problem in step 2. In order to dynamically change connections, I have to use variables other than i,j in FOR statement. But it seems to be not synthesizable for this pattern of using FOR loop(the synthesizing time goes unlimited.).

Would anyone help me out of this?

The problematic code segment is as follows:

```
FSM1: process(clk) is
variable cnt1 : integer range 0 to 5 := 0;
variable cnt2 : integer range 0 to 32-1 := 0;
variable cnt3 : integer range 0 to 24-1 := 0;
variable BlockBaseX : integer range 0 to 310 := 0;
variable BlockBaseY : integer range 0 to 230 := 0;
variable varPRLLc_ave_indata : std_logic_vector(400*8-1 downto 0) :=(others=>'0');
begin
if rising_edge(clk) then
    PRLLc_ave_indata <= varPRLLc_ave_indata;
    if stateFSM2A = s3 then
        case stateFSM1 is
            when s1 =>
                if do_InitCopy = '1' then
                    workGD <= baseGD;
                end if;
                stateFSM1 <= s2;
            when s2 =>
                if do_NumProc = '1' then

                    case cnt1 is
                        when 0 =>
                            BlockBaseX := cnt2*10; -- 10, 20, ..., 310
                            BlockBaseY := cnt3*10; -- 10, 20, ..., 230

                            for i in 0 to 9 loop
                                for j in 0 to 9 loop  -- PRLLc_ave_indata (400*8-1 downto 0);
                                    if i = 9 then
                                        if j = 9 then
                                            varPRLLc_ave_indata((i*10+j)*32+31 downto (i*10+j)*32) := workGD(BlockBaseY+i, BlockBaseX+j) & workGD(BlockBaseY+i, BlockBaseX+j-1) & workGD(BlockBaseY+i-1, BlockBaseX+j) & workGD(BlockBaseY+i-1, BlockBaseX+j-1);
                                        else
                                            varPRLLc_ave_indata((i*10+j)*32+31 downto (i*10+j)*32) := workGD(BlockBaseY+i, BlockBaseX+j) & workGD(BlockBaseY+i, BlockBaseX+j+1) & workGD(BlockBaseY+i-1, BlockBaseX+j) & workGD(BlockBaseY+i-1, BlockBaseX+j+1);
                                        end if;                                         
                                    else
                                        if j = 9 then
                                            varPRLLc_ave_indata((i*10+j)*32+31 downto (i*10+j)*32) := workGD(BlockBaseY+i, BlockBaseX+j) & workGD(BlockBaseY+i, BlockBaseX+j-1) & workGD(BlockBaseY+i+1, BlockBaseX+j) & workGD(BlockBaseY+i+1, BlockBaseX+j-1);                                            
                                        else
                                            varPRLLc_ave_indata((i*10+j)*32+31 downto (i*10+j)*32) := workGD(BlockBaseY+i, BlockBaseX+j) & workGD(BlockBaseY+i, BlockBaseX+j+1) & workGD(BlockBaseY+i+1, BlockBaseX+j) & workGD(BlockBaseY+i+1, BlockBaseX+j+1);                                            
                                        end if;
                                    end if;
                                end loop;
                            end loop;
-- If the above For loop is replaced with the following one(BlockBaseX,BlockBaseY are removed), the synthesis can be accomplished. 
--                              for i in 0 to 9 loop
--                                  for j in 0 to 9 loop  -- PRLLc_ave_indata (400*8-1 downto 0);
--                                      if i = 9 then
--                                          if j = 9 then
--                                              varPRLLc_ave_indata((i*10+j)*32+31 downto (i*10+j)*32) := workGD(i, j) & workGD(i, j-1) & workGD(i-1, j) & workGD(i-1, j-1);
--                                          else
--                                              varPRLLc_ave_indata((i*10+j)*32+31 downto (i*10+j)*32) := workGD(i, j) & workGD(i, j+1) & workGD(i-1, j) & workGD(i-1, j+1);
--                                          end if;                                         
--                                      else
--                                          if j = 9 then
--                                              varPRLLc_ave_indata((i*10+j)*32+31 downto (i*10+j)*32) := workGD(i, j) & workGD(i, j-1) & workGD(i+1, j) & workGD(i+1, j-1);                                            
--                                          else
--                                              varPRLLc_ave_indata((i*10+j)*32+31 downto (i*10+j)*32) := workGD(i, j) & workGD(i, j+1) & workGD(i+1, j) & workGD(i+1, j+1);                                            
--                                          end if;
--                                      end if;
--                                  end loop;
--                              end loop;                               

                        when 1 =>
                        when 2 =>
                        when 3 => -- got answer

                        when 4 =>
                        when others =>

                    end case;

                    if cnt1 < 5 then
                        cnt1 := cnt1 + 1;
                    else
                        cnt1 := 0;

                        if cnt2 < 32 then
                            cnt2 := cnt2 + 1;
                        else
                            cnt2 := 0;
                            if cnt3 < 24 then
                                cnt3 := cnt3 + 1;
                            else
                                cnt3 := 0;
                                stateFSM1 <= s3;

                            end if;                                         

                        end if;

                    end if;



                else

                end if;
            when s3 => -- after detecting a signal indicating OV7670 module has come to the requested point,
                          -- launch the pump out function - pump data from WorkGD to a stream
            when others =>

        end case;

    else
        stateFSM1 <= s1;
    end if;
end if;
end process FSM1;
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what variable name you use for iterating in a for-loop. If synthesis is running for a long time, it means that the tool has not yet found a suitable solution for your logic with the available resources. Could you tell us the following: Does synthesis never stop? Does it throw some error? how long has the synthesis been running? Which FPGA, which tool?? Also please take a look at [this](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Welcome-Join/Synthesis-taking-too-long/td-p/653146). Also, using `variables` in vhdl often causes synthesis problems. Try using `signals` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I had waited for 2 hours and didn't see synthesis stopped. No error was thrown through the synthesis.  FPGA is Altera CycloneIV E, EP4CE10F17C8. Develop tool is Quartus II 13.1.0. And if I use only i, j  in the loop body, (as shown in the commented area in the code segment),it can finish synthesis in 1 minite.

Comment: This will be because blockBase variables are not static and may change in runtime. Loop variables will be static. So the logic for both is different (and the i/j is likely far simpler)

Comment: Do you mean to use signals for BlockBaseX/Y instead of variables? Or anything changing is not prefered in a loop, the loop can only generate fixed structures? Well I will get a try to test. Thank you.